# Why does getActionView() return null

Tags: java, android

I've been searching for a solution for this for hours now. I just want to add a switch under the ActionBar (like in Bluetooth settings). I found a similar question on here, but it was probably old. Anyways here's my code:

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch);
    switchButton = (Switch) item.getActionView();

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"   >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_switch"
    android:title="off/on"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/switchlayout"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.Switch" />

</menu>
```

switchlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/myswitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#1E88E5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But no matter what I do I always get:

> Attempt to invode ... getActionView()' on a null object reference

I'm confused because i just defined item the line before `R.id.myswitch` is defined, did I mess that up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the simple mistype (it should be `menu_switch` to match your XML), per the [action view training](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html#action-view), you have to use [MenuItemCompat.getActionView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#getActionView(android.view.MenuItem)) to extract the `ActionView` (and, in your case, cast it to `SwitchCompat` as there is no `android.support.v7.widget.Switch`).

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_switch);
    switchButton = (SwitchCompat) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: I checked the link https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views#action-view and there's no `MenuItemCompat.getActionView` there. THe link also suggests to use `searchItem.getActionView();`

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch);
```

with

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_switch);
```

Beacause your item's id in menu xml is menu_switch,not myswitch.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [MenuItemCompat](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#getActionView(android.view.MenuItem)) with static function:

```
MenuItemCompat.getActionView (MenuItem item)
```

Comment: This is also correct, but the other guy's was first. Thanks!